# How to use values passed in HTTP Request in Logic Apps / Assign Values to Logic App Parameters Dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to make a generic Logic App(LA) to do some processing on some files. Calling the Logic App from ADF and able to pass the correct File Names. However I am not able to use/assign values passed to the Logic App to the parameters defined in the LA.  What am I Missing ? Please see the screenshot.

-Thanks

[image]

Sample Execution to show the names are passed properly.

[image]

Comment: Hi Akshay, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have problem or I misunderstand your problem, please let me know.

Comment: Shen,  please have a look at my post and let me know if you did anything different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, we can't assign `PRM_FileName` from the body of the request to one parameter. But we can use expression to get the value of `PRM_FileName`.

The expression should be `triggerBody()?['PRM_FileName']`. You can also assign `PRM_FileName` to a variable (for example named `var1`) and you can use the `var1` in your next actions but not use the expression(shown as below screenshot).
[image]

============================**Update**===========================

Below is my logic app:

[image]

I did everything what you mentioned in your 3 steps except I put the `PRM_FileName` in the body of the request but not appending it at the end of url.

[image]

============================**Update 2**===========================

Please use same schema with mine:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "PRM_FileName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

And then select the `PRM_FileName` into the variable directly(shown as below screenshot).
[image]

The expression should be `triggerBody()?['PRM_FileName']`, but in your screenshot the expression is `triggerOutputs()['queries']['PRM_FileName']`.

Comment: Hi Shen.  Thank you for providing a solution.  However I have figured out that to retrieve values 3 steps are necessary which gives a desired result somewhat.

1) Add a Method "POST" in the Logic App HTTP Trigger
2) The body must have property that needs to be received (e.g. PRM_FILEName)
3) Pass parameter at the end of URL by appending & like https://****&PRM_FILEName='ABC.TXT'

Then retrieved value can be assigned to a Variable but NOT TO Parameter.

Did you have to follow the above 3 points or there is something else ?

Comment: Hi @Akshay Sorry for the delay, please refer to my "Update" in answer. I did everything what you mentioned in your 3 steps except I put the `PRM_FileName` in the body of the request but not appending it at the end of url. And I don't think we can get the value of `PRM_FileName` in a variable if we append it at the end of post url without do anything else.

Comment: Shen, If I don't append the URL, I can't get values transferred.  But you suggest that it is not required ?

Comment: @Akshay Just put the `PRM_FileName` in the body of your post request instead of append it at the end of the url. As the screenshot of postman I provided in my "Update" answer.

Comment: @Akshay Since it is a `post` method(not `get` method), we should put the params in request body but not append them at the end of the url.

Comment: You are correct.That was my thought as well as the body would suffice and URL wouldn't need to be appended.  However I was not able to have a  successful execution. Posting a screenshot for your reference separately.

Comment: I see that you have used "type" : "object" at the end. This is something that I am missing in my logic. Let me try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220119/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-akshay).

Comment: Thank you Shen for spending time on this and providing a solution !!